# Xcode Thread 1 : Is it always main UI thread?

Tags: ios, xcode, thread-safety

Xcode shows threads in Debug navigator.

They are numbered: `Thread 1`, `Thread 2`, etc

I notice that I am always in Thread 1. Is it correct assumption that it is main UI thread?
I use libs/SDK like `Facebook` and `AFNetworking` they have callbacks and delegates. 
But thread safety is not always properly documented.

Comment: It better be, otherwise the majority of apps would go down in a burst of flames when they tried to use UIKit from a background thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't recall which, but in one of the WWDC videos (from 2011, I think), I heard an engineer mention that the UIKit internals assume thread 1 is UI.

So yes, it's not "simply" best practice, I think there are concrete technical dependencies.

As far as specific documentation, I don't readily find an "official" statement; but I think it's because it's even more foundational than that. For example, this kind of casual mention of the main thread's role is all over the place (taken from [the iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW11) (e.g. iOS 101)

> The main thread is where your app handles touch events and other user input.